# ssrs:add null value to multi value parameter didn't work

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2016

in order to allow a selection of null value in multi value parameter in SSRS project
we can use the query for the data set

```
Select ID,Value From SpecificTable
Union All
Select NULL,'Other'
```

in order to let null value returned from parameter when 'other' string is selected from parameter available selections

note:in available values section at parameters properties  i have chosen ID Column as Value Field and Value as Label Filed

i have tried the previous query with no be benefit ,the string 'other' doesn't appear as available selection for the parameter when i preview the report

are there any additional configurations that i should apply ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it this way... that's why "Allow Nulls" is an option.. what you can do is set the ID value for Other to some obscure value.. like -99.. which the actual ID from the specifiectable can never be.. and modify your stored procedure to say..

```
where (@id = sometable.someidcolumn or @id = -99)
```

This should in effect ignore the ID selection! Unless you want it to do something else of course.. then you code accordingly in the where clause.